# How do you suppress imputed data and only display results for the pooled data?

Tags: statistics, spss

I've done 15 imputations and am now running various tests on the new data, but all I'm really interested in is the pooled results at the end. The long list of imputations (especially in a test like an independent T) is unnecessary and I'd like to just hide all of it/suppress it when I run any tests on imputed data. is there anyway to do that in SPSS Statistics 22?

Using OMS Control Panel, this is the syntax it returns when I try to prevent the imputations from showing up:

```
* OMS.
OMS
  /SELECT TABLES
  /IF COMMANDS=['Multiple Imputation']
  /DESTINATION VIEWER=NO.

DATASET ACTIVATE DataSet1.
T-TEST GROUPS=Group1(0 1)
  /MISSING=ANALYSIS
  /VARIABLES=Variable1 Variable2
  /CRITERIA=CI(.95).
```

Comment: To suppress particular output see the OMS command.

Comment: Thanks AndyW! I've added a request to hide all Tables identified under the Multiple Imputation command identifier, but all of those imputed tables are still there... Am I selecting the wrong thing?

Comment: If you post your code it may help. Did you include the option `VIEWER=NO` on the `DESTINATION` subcommand?

Comment: I'm pretty new at this part of SPSS and I'm not using any commands, I'm just using the UI. However, I added the code that choosing paste in OMS Control Panel spits out to my original question!

Comment: I thought I had it working, but it turns out I just turned off the splitting by accident... The syntax in my main post is what I'm using and it is still returning everything.